# Derivative of real functions including Re and Im

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

When deriving functions using `Re`, `Im` or `Arg` (and probably some other functions as well), Mathematica gives nonsensical results, e.g.

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], D[Re[Gamma[I x]], x]]
(*
==> I Gamma[I x] PolyGamma[0, I x] Re'[Gamma[I x]]
*)
```

Of course the wanted result would be `-Im[Gamma[I x] PolyGamma[0, I x]]`. Now in this case, it is easy to resolve, but often those functions are deeply inside a complicated expression. Therefore my question is:

Is there any way to get reasonable derivatives for real functions of real parameters which involve `Re`, `Im` etc. of complex expressions depending on those variables?

Comment: How would you define the derivative of Im, Arg, and Re? Do these functions have a derivative?

Comment: @Searke: If `x` is a real variable, then `D[Re[f[x]],x]` is `Re[f'[x]]`, `D[Im[f[x]],x]` is `Im[f'[x]]` and `D[Arg[f[x]],x]` is `Im[f'[x]/f[x]]`. I don't think this can be handled by giving a value to `Re'[f[x]]`, `Im'[f[x]]` and `Arg'[f[x]]` (but if I'm wrong and it can, that would allow to fix up the expression using simple replacement rules).

Comment: Leonid Shifrin´s answer below is correct. The real issue here is conceptual. If there is no definition for the derivative of of these functions, then you cannot take their derivative.

Comment: @Searke: I do not want to take the derivative of `Re`, `Im` and `Arg`, I want to take the derivative of functions of real variables *containing* them. And those derivatives *are* defined (as long as the functions are otherwise well-behaved).

Comment: How would you handle the fact that the chain rule from calculus no longer holds?

D[Im@f@x,x] = Im´[f[x]] f´[x]

Comment: By special-casing that case, of course. But thinking of it, maybe it makes sense to treat `Im'` as acting on functions instead of values, with `Im'[f[x]] = Im[f'[x]]/f'[x]`. I'll have to think about that idea.

Comment: @celtschk The answer I got in my answer just now corresponds to your desired answer (though it's not in the same simple form). I went the route of least resistance (i.e., least hacking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Jens' directional derivative functions convinced me that fixing after the fact is indeed possible; however it doesn't give nice results for non-specified symbolic functions. On the other hand, Heike's solution handles those quite nicely, but needs to modify global state, which I consider acceptable for this case (but not everyone does, as Jens' comments prove), but nevertheless solutions without modifying global state are IMHO generally preferrable. By combining elements from both approaches I've come to the following solution which seems to work quite well and also treats the cases of `Abs` and `Arg`:

```
deriv[expr_,var_]:=
  D[expr,var]//.{Re'[e_]:>Re[D[e,var]]/D[e,var],
                 Im'[e_]:>Im[D[e,var]]/D[e,var],
                 Arg'[e_]:>Im[D[e,var]/e]/D[e,var],
                 Abs'[e_]:>(Re[e] Re[D[e,var]] + Im[e] Im[D[e,var]])/     
                           (Abs[e] D[e,var])}
```

With this I get

```
deriv[Re[Gamma[I x]],x]
(*
==> -Im[Gamma[I x] PolyGamma[0, I x]]
*)
deriv[Re[f[Re[f[x]]]],x]
(*
==> Re[Re[f'[x]] f'[Re[f[x]]]]
*)
%//Simplify
(*
==> Re[f'[x]] Re[f'[Re[f[x]]]]
*)
```

Comment: OK, I think I have waited long enough :-)

Comment: Your 4.5-year wait may be over: I had problem with this approach when trying to compute a Jacobian matrix.  For example, `f[x_] := Re[Sqrt[x]]` then `D[{f[x], f[y]}, {{x, y}}]` doesn't work.  However @Heike's above answer did work for this problem.

Answer (score 25):

The functions Re and Im (just as `Conjugate`) don't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations and are therefore not analytic. That means their derivative is not uniquely defined in the complex plane. That's the reason why `Re'` and `Im'` can't be simplified.

Therefore, we have to be more specific about how we want the limit to be done that corresponds to the desired derivative. The cleanest way of doing that is this simple replacement for the derivative:

```
Limit[(Gamma[I (x + ε)] - Gamma[I x])/ε, ε -> 0]
```

> $i \Gamma (i x) \psi ^{(0)}(i x)$

Now I'll try to apply this to the real part instead:

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Limit[(Re[Gamma[I (x + ε)]] - Re[Gamma[I x]])/ε, ε -> 0]]
```

> $-\Im(\psi ^{(0)}(i x)) \Re(\Gamma (i x))-\Im(\Gamma (i x))
>    \Re(\psi ^{(0)}(i x))$

So we don't get any of the pesky `Re'` here. For those who don't like the $\LaTeX$ format, here is the real output:

```
-Im[PolyGamma[0, I x]] Re[Gamma[I x]] - Im[Gamma[I x]] Re[PolyGamma[0, I x]]
```

**Edit: generalization**

Motivated by the discussion of Heike's answer, I wrote a definition of a directional derivative in an arbitrary direction in the complex plane. I did this to show that such a definition can be made without in any way modifying [`SystemOptions` (see in particular "More Information")](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetSystemOptions.html).

```
dirDeriv[f_, var_, angle_: 0] := Module[{g, x},
  g = f /. var -> x;
  Assuming[x ∈ Reals,
   D[g, x] /. (h_'[p_] :> h'[p]/D[p, x]) /. (h_'[p_] :> 
       Limit[(h[p /. x -> x + ε Exp[I angle]] - 
            h[p])/ε/Exp[I angle], ε -> 0]) /. 
    x -> var
   ]
  ]
```

The first argument is the function to be differentiated, the second argument is the name of the independent variable, which will be treated as a real number. The third (optional) argument is the phase angle of the line in the complex plane along which the limit for the derivative is taken. By default this angle is zero corresponding to the real axis (the result depends on the angle only if the first argument is non-analytic).

Here is how to apply this function as a replacement for the standard derivative:

```
dirDeriv[Re[Gamma[I x]], x]
```

> $-\Im(\psi ^{(0)}(i x)) \Re(\Gamma (i x))-\Im(\Gamma (i x))
>    \Re(\psi ^{(0)}(i x))$

A simpler example is

```
dirDeriv[Re[Exp[I x^2]], x]
```

> $-2 x \sin \left(x^2\right)$

The function works by doing the standard derivative and then looking for any occurrences of `Re'`, `Im'` and others (in fact, anything looking like `h_'[p_]`). These patterns are then replaced by first *undoing* the chain rule that Mathematica automatically applies (that's the division by `D[p, x]`), and then calculating the directional derivative  as a limit analogous to the example above.

With this function one can easily explore the direction dependence of the derivative for non-analytic functions. For example,

```
Table[dirDeriv[Re[x], x, angle], {angle, 0, Pi, Pi/4}]
```

> `{1, 1/2 - I/2, 0, 1/2 + I/2, 1}`

**Edit 2: numerical functions**

The above discussion concerns *symbolic* directional derivatives of possibly non-analytic functions. The situation is in some ways much simpler if the goal is to do  **numerical differentiation**, i.e., calculate the derivative of a function `f[x]` which is numeric when the argument `x` is numeric.

For that case, one can go straight to the numerical approach by doing this:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
ND[Re[Gamma[I x]], x, 1]
```

With the [numerical derivative `ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html), you can for example make plots directly. Here is a comparison of the symbolic result with the numerical one:

```
Plot[{
  -Im[PolyGamma[0, I x0]] Re[Gamma[I x0]] - 
   Im[Gamma[I x0]] Re[PolyGamma[0, I x0]], 
   ND[Re[Gamma[I x]], x, x0]},
  {x0, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dotted}]
```

[image: comparison of numerical and analytical derivatives]

Comment: That looks like a solution! However for some reason packaging that into a function doesn't seem to work: After `Dr[expr_, var_]:=Assuming[Element[var, Reals],Limit[((expr/.var->(var+eps))-expr)/eps, eps->0]]` the expression `Dr[Re[Gamma[I x]], x]` gives `0`. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution: Just wrap the whole thing in `With[{e = expr}, ...]` and use `e` inside. With that it works just great!

Comment: @celtschk Hm, I tried your original function and it worked, too... maybe you had some global variable floating around. Anyway, looks like you figured out how to do the replacement.

Comment: Nice solution, +1. Looks obvious in retrospect, I wish I had thought about it. I think a much simpler way (w.r.t. Cauchy - Riemann conditions) of seeing that these functions are non-analytic is to notice that they *necessarily* depend on both `z` and `zbar`, while CR equations are a way of saying that the function depends on `z` only (in addition to the existence of the derivatives).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for leaving something for me to do. Usually when I get to this site you and a bunch of others are already done with all the fun stuff...  Whether one considers the CR equations simple is probably a matter of taste. To me, they provide the most straightforward condition. But then again, I just taught them last term, so I'm biased.

Comment: nice; you have my vote already so I can't re-upvote. As an aside, in writing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6332142/559318) answer I noticed that both `ND` and `N[D[...,x]]` actually return the directional derivative as well (at least if you prevent `D` from peeking inside your function)

Comment: @acl I hadn't seen that post yet, thanks!

Comment: @Jens: I see this great leading insightful answer right now. Thanks for sharing me that in the answer you gave me before. +1

Answer (score 9):

Since the derivative of `Re[f[x]]` and `Im[f[x]]` with respect to a real variable `x` is `Re[f'[x]]` and `Im[f'[x]]`, respectively, one strategy for calculating the derivatives would be exclude `Re` and `Im` when differentiating the expression and then to replace any occurrences of `D[Re[a], b]` and `D[Im[a], b]` with `Re[D[a, b]]` and `Im[D[a, b]]`.

First we need to prevent `Re` and `Im` from being differentiated. We do this by adding them to the list given by `SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"]` using `SetSystemOptions`:

```
excl = SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"][[1, 2, 1, 2]];
SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> 
  "ExcludedFunctions" -> Union[Join[excl, {Re, Im}]]];
```

Now, when you're trying to differentiate an expression involving `Re` and `Im` Mathematica will apply the chain rule but leaves expressions of the form `D[Re[f[x], x]` unevaluated, e.g.

```
D[Sin[Re[I x^2 + 5 x]], x]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The next step is to replace the derivatives of the real or imaginary part of a function with the real or imaginary part of the derivative of the function:

```
deriv[exp_, x__] := D[exp, x] /. {HoldPattern[D[Re[a_], b__]] :> Re[D[a, b]],
    HoldPattern[D[Im[a_], b__]] :> Im[D[a, b]]}
```

**Example**

```
deriv[Re[Gamma[I x]], x]

(* ==>  -Im[Gamma[I x] PolyGamma[0, I x]] *)
```

Comment: A very interesting solution. It has the advantage that it also nicely works with symbolic functions (`deriv[Re[f[x]],x]` gives `Re[f'[x]]`), however as is it doesn't work with nested `Re`/`Im`, e.g. `deriv[Re[f[Re[f[x]]]],x]` gives `Re[D[Re[f[x]], x] f'[Re[f[x]]]]`. However, replacing `/.` with `//.` seems to fix that. It has the disadvantage that you modify global state, but since I cannot imagine any case where I'd want `Re'` or `Im'`, that's acceptable. Another nice feature is that it's extendable; you can also treat other (e.g. self-written) functions specially. I'll therefore move accept.

Comment: But is it really worth it having no more ability to simplify `D[Re[z^2], z]`? Not sure about that - but have to go now...

Comment: @Heike With your modification, there is a significant change in the behavior of `D[Re[Exp[I x]], x] /. x -> 1`. This cannot be good.

Comment: @Jens If you're worried about possible side effects you could put the `SetSystemOptions` statement in the definition of `deriv`, do the derivation, and reset the `SystemOptions` to their original state.

Comment: @Heike That won't solve it. Try `deriv[D[Re[Exp[I x z]], z] /. z -> 1, x]`

Comment: @Jens What do you mean with `D[Re[Exp[I x z]], z]`?Since `Re` isn't an analytic function, `D[Re[f[z]], z]` isn't defined for complex `z` (and analytic `f`). You could define a directional derivative (which is basically what `deriv` is doing for the real direction). So if you want to take the derivative wrt `z` in the real direction you could do `deriv[deriv[Re[Exp[I x z]], z] /. z -> 1, x]` which produces `-Im[E^(I x)] - Re[E^(I x) x]` as expected. To take the derivative in another direction, `a` say, you could substitute `z` with `a y` and take the derivative wrt `y` instead.

Comment: @Heike sure, but if I say `D[Re[Exp[I x z]], z] /. z -> 1` then I'd still prefer to get a correct answer like `I E^(I x) x Derivative[1][Re][E^(I x)]` rather than an _error_!

Comment: I wouldn't consider `I E^(I x) x Derivative[1][Re][E^(I x)]` correct either to be honest. Mathematica is using the chain rule here which isn't valid since `Re` isn't differentiable.

Comment: At least it's a consistent definition. For example, it leads to the result `x D[Re[ x z], x] - z D[Re[ x z], z] == 0` independently of `x` and `z`. On the other hand, with your definition, I put the last statement into a second derivative and get `deriv[x D[Re[x z], x] - z D[Re[ x z], z], x] == -z + Re[z]` instead of zero.

Comment: I get `x deriv[Re[ x z], x] - z deriv[Re[ x z], z]] == -z Re[x] + x Re[z]` which is the correct result. It's only  equal to 0 if both `x` and `z` are real, but in that case `-z+Re[z]==0` as well.

Comment: Yes, but that's trivial and doesn't address the consistency issue in the wider domain.

Comment: @Jens: I'd consider anything containing `Re'` as an error. What should `Re'[E^I]` *mean?* You know, the chain rule has *preconditions*: It says $(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$ *provided* that $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$ and $g$ is differentiable at $x$. For unknown functions, on derivation it makes sense to assume they are differentiable unless you know otherwise. `Re` is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @celtschk In Mathematica, I think it's simply part of the paradigm to allow Re' etc. E.g., you can also literally write `D["whatever"[z^2], z]`. The purpose here is that you have the freedom to make sense of such expressions at a later stage. Same for `Re`: you yourself are attempting to make sense of `Re'` in a limited domain with your question. It just has to be done consistently. I'm sure you'll be able to avoid inconsistencies in your application, but for my taste this solution is too invasive.