# Can Mathematica help a theorem to be alive?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, programming

We are used to do limits by means of $\epsilon, \delta$. This is the first step an student encounters limits. Using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ leads him to be familiar to Logic. I have taught limits and other basic similar concepts and I did that by using Maple instead of Mathematica. Because of that, writing a program in which we can probe a real function like sin$(x)$ has a limit has been my old wish. This needs a computer-assisted analytic approach in which we are able to define $\epsilon, \delta$ randomly in $\mathbb R$ and then verify if a certain well-behaved function has a limit. Here, I am not intended to use packages. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a visual look at the behavior? Or a computer-assisted analytic proof of something (maybe the Intermediate Value Theorem?)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  You will need to edit your question to provide a more solid description of your problem or it will be closed as "not a real question."  If the community votes to close it you can still improve it and it may be reopened.  Also, you have enough "reputation" to talk in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) -- that may be helpful!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for the comment and for your time. Honestly, I should have edited my question in time but I couldn't. As you kindly noted, I'd like to have a computer-assisted analytic approach rather than just seeing what happenes. In fact, how can we define $\epsilon, \delta$ in which a program be able to probe a certain limit?

Comment: If the edit to my answer goes in the direction you want, maybe you can add to your question some more details on what you mean by a "computer-assisted approach" - my interpretation of "enlivening" a theorem is not the same as "proving" a theorem. But one has to know more about how you want to illuminate the theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For visualizations, maybe the following Wolfram Demonstrations will give some genreal idea of what has been done:

- [Limit Laws](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LimitLaws/)
- [Finite Limit at Infinity](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FiniteLimitAtInfinity/)
- [Limits: A Graphical and Numerical Approach](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LimitsAGraphicalAndNumericalApproach/)
- [A Noncontinuous Limit of a Sequence of Continuous Functions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ANoncontinuousLimitOfASequenceOfContinuousFunctions/)

**Edit**

For an analytical approach to derivatives using limits, you could just apply the technique I proposed [in this more specialized answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3812/245):

It just uses the command `Limit`, as in this simple example:

```
Limit[(Sin[x + d] - Sin[x])/d, d -> 0]

(* ==> Cos[x] *)
```