# Strange behaviour of MMA in derivatives of some standard functions

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

There are some peculiar things to be discovered in derivatives of some standard functions in MMA:

**Strange behaviour**

*Example 1: Abs*

We have

```
Abs[0.1]

(* Out[72]= 0.1 *)
```

But

```
Abs'[0.1]

(* Out[73]= Derivative[1][Abs][0.1] *)
```

Same thing if we avoid writing the prime:

```
D[Abs[x], x] /. x -> 0.1

(* Out[110]= Derivative[1][Abs][0.1] *)
```

That is, the derivative of `Abs[]` has no numerical value.
When plotted, there's nothing to be seen.

The derivative should of course be, or at least behave like, `Sign[x]` .

*Example 2: Sign*

Sign[0.1]

(* Out[78]= 1 *)

Sign'[0.1]

(* Out[79]= Derivative[1][Sign][0.1] *)

That is, the derivative of `Sign[]` has no numerical value.
When plotted, there's nothing to be seen.

*Example 3: Floor*

```
Floor[0.1]

(* Out[80]= 0 *)
```

But which value has the derivative at 0 ?

First possibility:

```
Floor'[0]

(* Out[89]= Derivative[1][Floor][0] *)
```

No value.

Second possibility:

```
Floor[0.]

(* Out[90]= 0 *)
```

Hence the numerical value seems to be 0.

No, bad luck, wrong guess! Look at that

Third possibility:

N[Floor'[0]]

(* Out[93]= 36.2120995105236639865598801739718338716778459859 *)

Furthermore:

```
Table[{x, N[Floor'[x], 5]}, {x, 0, 1/2, 0.05}]

(* Out[96]= {{0., 36.212}, {0.05, 12.5946}, {0.1, -4.29432}, {0.15, 
  1.61679}, {0.2, -0.532708}, {0.25, 0.13901}, {0.3, -0.0263362}, {0.35, 
  0.00318987}, {0.4, -0.000184538}, {0.45, 0.}, {0.5, 0.}} *)
```

Strange ocillatory behaviour for a quantity which should be = 0 throughout.
It seems to be defined via a Fourier series.

**Remedy ?: do it yourself !**

Finally, let's create the derivative by ourselves as it is originally defined:

```
floorPrime[x_] := Limit[(1/h) (Floor[x + h] - Floor [x]), h -> 0]

Plot[0.1 + floorPrime[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]

(* Picture snipped *)


absPrime[x_] := Limit[(1/h) (Abs[x + h] - Abs[x]), h -> 0]

Plot[absPrime[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]

(* Picture snipped *)
```

Ok, everything fine.

But why has MMA such problems with its own standard operation ' (or D[]) in this class of functions? Please explain.

**Edit 15.09.14**

There has been quite a lot of discussion here but no answer. I gather that the answers to similar topics referenced in the comments here are considered sufficient.
These are:

[Derivative of real functions including Re and Im](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/derivative-of-real-functions-including-re-and-im)

[Symbolic derivatives are being calculated numerically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29329/symbolic-derivatives-are-being-calculated-numerically)

Because these references are pretty comprehensive I don't know if my question has contributed anything new, and the surprise was only on my side.

Let me nevertheless add some further observations which show that in some cases the documentation points out Possible Issues. But this is not done consistently. In one case WolframAlpha gives the expected result which MMA has refused to give.

1a) `Abs'[0.1]` is not evaluated.

But WolframAlpha "knows better":

```
WolframAlpha["Abs'[0.1]"];

(* -> 1 *)
```

1b) Trying to tell Mathematica that `x` is not complex but real (in which case the derivative is well defined)

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, D[Abs[x], x]]

(* -> Derivative[1][Abs][x] *)
```

doesn't work either.

1c) Abs Possible Issues says:
No series can be formed from Abs for complex arguments:

```
Series[Abs[x], {x, 0, 2}]

(* -> Abs[x] *)
```

For real arguments, a series can be found:

```
Series[Abs[x], {x, 0, 2}, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```

$\begin{array}{ll}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{ll}
 -x+O[x]^3 & x\leq 0 \\
 x+O[x]^3 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

1d) UnitStep Possible Issues says:
Differentiating Abs does not yield UnitStep:

```
D[Abs[t], t]

(* Derivative[1][Abs][t] *)
```

2) HeavisideTheta / DiracDelta Possible Issues say:

The functions UnitStep and HeavisideTheta are not mathematically equivalent:

```
{HeavisideTheta[x], UnitStep[x]}
Integrate[D[%, x], x]

(* -> {HeavisideTheta[x], UnitStep[x]} *)
```

Only HeavisideTheta gives DiracDelta after Differentiation.

```
{HeavisideTheta[x], UnitStep[x], (Sqrt[x^2]/x + 1)/2, (Abs[x]/x + 1)/2};

D[%, x] // Together
```

$\left\{\text{DiracDelta}[x],
\begin{array}{ll}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{Indeterminate} & x==0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,0,\frac{-\text{Abs}[x]+x \text{Abs}'[x]}{2 x^2}\right\}$

3) Conjugate Possible Issues says:
Differentiating Conjugate is not possible:

```
D[Conjugate[t], t]
(* Derivative[1][Conjugate][t] *)
```

A similar remark should be placed in the documentation under Possible Issues consistently.

4) Sign' behaves similar as Abs'

```
Sign'[0.1]

(* Derivative[1][Sign][0.1] *)

WolframAlpha["Sign[0.1]"];
(* -> 1 *)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: The functions you explore are all non-analytic as complex functions, thus the derivative is undefined.  You might explore the numerical derivative `ND` as defined the `NumericalCalculus` package.

Comment: @Marc: I don't agree. The derivative of these functions as real functions is well defined except for certain points. I have shown this in the section Remedy? But MMA has difficulties also outside these points.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if you agree or not - the basic fact is that `D` works in the complex domain and these functions are not differentiable in that context.  That, quite simply, is the explanation of the behavior you see.  Now, whether *you* would prefer different behavior and how you might implement it is a different question.

Comment: A similar thing happens with `Re` and `Im`. While those functions are obviously meant to work in the complex realm, I think an understanding of what is going on there is relevant.  [This discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/derivative-of-real-functions-including-re-and-im) might help in that regard.

Comment: @Marc: I know perfectly well what analyticity of functions means. But I was talking about MMA here. Please tell me where your assertion about D can be found in the documentation.

Comment: Well, I guess it's not just `D` but the general fact that symbolic computation assumes symbols are complex. Many computations performed by Mathematica must be fully understood in this context - from `Simplify[Abs[x^2]]` to the apparent missing branch of the cube root in `Plot[x^(1/3), {x,-1,1}]`. There are exceptions, particularly the `CubeRoot` and `Surd` functions introduced in V9 but, generally, computations are done in the complex numbers and I assure you that this is the context in which you need to explore your question.

Comment: Incidentally, `Derivative` is not protected, so you can easily define your own DownValues: Thus, `Abs'[x_] := Sign[x]; Abs'[0.5]` produces `1`.

Comment: This issue has been visited before http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29329/193

Comment: @belisarius Your question seems to be exactly opposite of the one here - namely, `Plot[Derivative[f]...]` uses a finite difference scheme on discrete functions, such as `IntegerPart`, `Round` and several others.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I haven't marked it as dup. I wanted to leave a link here for those researching problems with derivatives of non-analytic functions in the future

Comment: @MarkMcClure My view, perhaps wrong, is that it is not `D` per se but `Abs`, `Floor`, etc. that are defined as functions of a complex variable.  That `D` takes the complex derivative follows naturally.  @Dr. Hintze, I recall reading somewhere that *Mathematica* makes no restriction on what the variables represent unless explicitly stated.  So numeric functions are functions of a complex variable, unless the documentation or an error message states that it has to be real or an integer or whatever.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for your comprehensive replies and suggestions. I hope it is obvious that - as a year long user - I was just surprised to get rather unexpected result when I do things which are completely "legal". i.e. without giving rise to warnings. This can lead to errors more of less hidden (think of having Floor somewhere in a Long expression of which you need to take the derivative, and then have some numerical calculation do to: the spurious oscillations spoil the result).

Comment: @Michael E2: I'm a bit confused. I gather from your comments to Mark and me that you consider it permitted to calculate D[Abs[z],z]: you state Abs[] is defined as a function of a complex variable, and there's no hint in the documentation of something else, and also there's no error message appearing when being used.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, Yes, `D[Abs[z], z]` is permitted. I believe one can take `D` of almost anything (early example: `D[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]^2, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]` -- impressive and pointless at the same time). There are restrictions on what is allowed for a variable (second argument). However, the `Derivative` of `Abs` is undefined, but still permitted. There's some wisdom in that, since you can define it to agree with the real function as Mark points out.

Comment: Here's another way to look at it:  In cases where the complex and real derivative have the same formula, you should find that `D` returns the expected result.  In cases where the complex and real derivatives do not agree, the `Derivative` should be undefined.

Comment: I have studied the documentation for all these discontinous functions and shall present an overview as an edit to my question, as soon as I find the time. Here's just one positive example: "Possible issues for Conjugate: Differentiating Conjugate is not possible: D[Conjugate[t], t] -> Derivative[1][Conjugate][t]". I think this should be mentioned with Abs too.

Comment: I tried to figure out what the question is about, but I honestly can't think of any way to answer here.

Comment: @ Jens: in order to find this out it might help to have a brief look at the fairly extensive comments here which are, as it were, kind of a "scattered" answer. I'm now fine with it.