# Getting strange result with derivative of Abs of a complex number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, numerical-value

So I am getting some results after a computation like:

```
(-0.741446 - 5.47358 I) Abs'[-0.702207 + 0.0951203 I]
```

The problem is the derivative in `Abs`. Could someone explain why I am getting this and how I can get rid of it? Why doesn't mathematica give me a number back instead and it gives derivative of Absolute value?

Comment: The complex absolute value is not differentiable. I don't know how to get rid of it in this case. It's not clear what value it should be. This works when you want the real absolute value: `Abs'[2] /. Abs -> RealAbs`. But that is not the case here.

Comment: Related: [(3810)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3810), [(8188)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8188), [(59503)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59503)

Comment: Suppose the result came from `D[Abs[Sin[t + I t]], t] /. t -> RandomReal[]`. Then the fix is `D[ComplexExpand@Abs[Sin[t + I t]], t] /. t -> RandomReal[]`. In other words, the solution to your problem cannot be inferred just from the result. You have to fix how the result was generated.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think this actually helps! Thanks! How can I mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: You can't accept comments.  I put them in an answer below, but the site's community would probably appreciate a more complete question. (You could just use the example from my comment, if it's reasonably representative of the problem.)

Comment: sorry I didn't add the code because it is really complex function of functions of functions..... and they have huge expressions which I am not explicitly printing not even in my code. What you added below though is really enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, my comments provided a solution. It might be better to have a more complete question, but here are my comments, slightly alter to show reproducible output:

> The complex absolute value is not differentiable. I don't know how to get rid of it in this case. It's not clear what value it should be. This works when you want the real absolute value: Abs'[2] /. Abs -> RealAbs. But that is not the case here. –
> Michael E2
> 33 mins ago

> Suppose the result came from
>
> ```
> D[Abs[Sin[t + I t]], t] /. t -> 1/3.
> (*  (1.10904 + 0.886847 I) [Abs'[0.345541 + 0.320851 I]  *)
> ```
>
> Then the fix is
>
> ```
> D[ComplexExpand@Abs[Sin[t + I t]], t] /. t -> RandomReal[]
> (8  1.41615  *)
> ```
>
> In other words, the solution to your problem cannot be inferred just from the result. You have to fix how the result was generated. –
> Michael E2
> 24 mins ago