# Phase unwrapping of transfer function model for calculating group delay

Tags: signal-processing, control-systems

Suppose that I have a transfer function model

```
TransferFunctionModel[{{{1.76073542174078*^7 + 15432.189447175271` s}}, 1.9007939847037695`*^7 + 17800.708617496595` s + 1. s^2}, s]
```

I want to calculate the group delay. So theoretically I need to differentiate the *Bode* phase diagrams with frequency. However, in this case, one should first unwrap the phase resulting from the Bode phase plot to get the correct result. I have seen other posts where the unwrapping phase in discrete data was discussed but could not find an appropriate method to apply directly on a transfer function (or maybe I missed something?).

**How can one use *Mathematica* to calculate the *"group delay"* using an appropriate phase unwrapping method?**

Comment: A similar post is [160962](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160962/group-delay-of-a-transfer-function).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the answers there made me a bit confused. The first example actually talk about wrapping the phase while I was looking for unwrapping the phase output from Bode plot. However I guess in this case possibly 0 - 360 as PhaseRange could work - have to check. The 2nd answer made me a bit more confused since it did indicate that the BodePlot gives out unwrapped phase while the original post claim otherwise. So does the BodePlot by default gives out wrapped around phase or unwrapped phase between 0 and 360? Thanks.