# Working with complex valued functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, complex

I have a function which has real and imaginary parts and I need to differentiate both parts separately. This is a simpler example of what I have tried, without success:

```
f[x_] = x^2 + I x^3
g[x_] = Re[f[x]]
h[x_] = g'[x]
```

but `h[1]` gives me `-3 Im'[1] + 2 Re'[1]`

How can I find such derivatives?

Comment: `D[f[x], x]` or `f'[x]` or `f'[1]` gives you the derivatives of the real and imaginary parts simultaneously.

Comment: How then can I extract, as a function, only the derivative of the imaginary part?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4099/69835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mma does not know in advance if x is real, or complex. Indeed, if one defines your function and tries to get its real part:

```
f[x_] := x^2 + I x^3
Re[f[x]]

(* -Im[x^3] + Re[x^2] *)
```

Mma returns the result as if x were complex. One can use the functionality of `Simplify`, to fix it:

```
Simplify[ Re[f[x]], x \[Element] Reals]
Simplify[ Im[f[x]], x \[Element] Reals]

(*  x^2

x^3   *)
```

There is, however another way, that may seem you comfortable. Assuming f[x], has already been defined, let us define its imaginary and real parts as follows:

```
    Ref[x_] := (List @@ f[x])[[1]]
IImf[x_] := (List @@ f[x])[[2]]
```

Then

```
    D[Ref[x], x]
D[IImf[x], x]

(*  2 x

3 I x^2  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: `ComplexExpand[]` will automatically assume real variables unless explicitly told otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
f[x_] := x^2 + I x^3
g[x_] := Re[f[x]]
h[x_] = g'[x] // ComplexExpand

h[1]
```

> `2`

Comment: Hi. The code failed in v13.