# ComplexExpand of Hypergeometric function

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex

I would like to take the derivative of the absolute-squared value of a hypergeometric function and plot the result, for real arguments

```
D[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Hypergeometric2F1[I s, I p, 1, x]]Hypergeometric2F1[I s, I p, 1, x]], x]
```

but the result is given in terms of the undefined function

```
Im'
```

I thought that `ComplexExpand` is supposed to be used to avoid this problem, it helps with some simple functions (like `Sin[x]`) but not with 2F1. Is there a better way to plot the derivative?
Note `s,p,x` are real.

Comment: Generally, `ComplexExpand[]` is not equipped to handle special functions like `Hypergeometric2F1[]`. In the meantime, have you already seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3810)?